# Proof involving Continuous Map and Disjoint Sets

Tags: real-analysis

I'm a bit confused about the following proof my analysis book gives about the following Theorem: Consider metric spaces $(S,d), (S^*, d^*)$ and let $f: S \to S^*$ be continuous. If $E$ is a connected subset of $S$, then $f(E)$ is a connected subset of $S^*$.

Proof: Assume $f(E)$ is not connected in $S^*$. Then there exist disjoint open sets $V_1, V_2$ in $S^*$ such that $f(E) \subseteq V_1 \cup V_2$, $f(E) \cap V_1 \neq \emptyset$ and $f(E) \cap V_2 \neq \emptyset$.

Let $U_1 = f^{-1}(V_1)$ and $U_2 = f^{-1}(V_2)$.

I know that $U_1, U_2$ are both open sets in $S$ since $f$ is continuous. But why are they disjoint?

My book also claims that $E \subseteq U_1 \cup U_2, E \cap U_1 \neq \emptyset$ and $E \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset$.

Since I know $f(E) \subseteq V_1 \cup V_2$, applying $f^{-1}$ to both sides gives the desired result. But in order to justify $E \cap U_1 \neq \emptyset$ and $E \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset$ that would mean $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$. Is this correct and why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U_1$ and $U_2$ have a common element $x$, then $f(x) \in V_1 $ and $f(x) \in V_2$, and this is absurd.

Comment: Right because $V_1, V_2$ are disjoint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint for "I know that $U_1,U_2$ are both open sets in S since f is continuous. But why are they disjoint?":

Can you prove $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$?

---

Hint for "$f^{−1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$: Is this correct and why is it?":

Did you try using the definition of $f^{-1}$ of a set?

Comment: I know that $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \{s \in S : f(s) \in \emptyset \}$. So is it trivial that $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$?